# SOAP RPC/Encoded convert to RPC/Literal

Tags: xml, soap, rpc

Does anyone know of a tool or 'blackbox' that would convert a RPC/Encoded WSDL to RPC/Literal?  I don't have the ability to change the API (it's not mine) but the tool I want to use does not support RPC/Encoded.  I'd like to see if someone has created a simple black box communication converter.

I want to use wave maker and i'm not a programmer so I'm looking for a tool to just take care of the translation.

Answer (score 5):

If you are changing the encoding of the WSDL, then the SOAP messages would change to:

RPC/Encoded Message Sample

```
<soap:envelope>
    <soap:body>
        <myMethod>
            <x xsi:type="xsd:int">5</x>
            <y xsi:type="xsd:float">5.0</y>
        </myMethod>
    </soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
```

RPC/Literal Message Sample

```
<soap:envelope>
    <soap:body>
        <myMethod>
            <x>5</x>
            <y>5.0</y>
        </myMethod>
    </soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
```

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/

So, it is not enough to translate the WSDL, as you can see de differences between SOAP messages.

You could create a component that acts like a middle man:

- call the target services in RPC/literal
- export functionality as RPC/encoded to your application

But this component needs to be implemented on your specific case, there is no magic tool.