# RPC/literal vs RPC/Encoded in Java WebService consumer

Tags: web-services, lotus-domino

I've a **RPC/Encoded** webservice provider that expose an attachment in base64 format.
Everything work fine, this is the output

```
 <multiRef id="id16" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns4:Documento" xmlns:ns4="urn:interpro_Documento.rfc205.regione.toscana.it" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
     <descr xsi:type="xsd:string">smime.p7s</descr>
     <ext xsi:type="xsd:string">p7s</ext>
     <document xsi:type="soapenc:base64">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</document>
  </multiRef>
```

The same webservice, in **RPC/Literal** format, expose this:

```
<documento>
           <descr>smime.p7s</desc>
           <ext>p7s</ext>
           <document>85</document>
           <document>69</document>
           <document>81</document>
           <document>53</document>
           <document>78</document>
           <document>71</document>
           <document>74</document>
           <document>88</document>
           <document>100</document>
           <document>50</document>
           <document>100</document>
           <document>107</document>
           <document>98</document>
           <document>86</document>
           <document>90</document>
           <document>53</document>
           <document>89</document>
           <document>122</document>
           <document>74</document>
           <document>115</document>
           .........
           .........
```

What's the problem? How can i have only one  tag with base64 format inside using RPC/Literal SOAP message format?

Comment: It may not matter, but FYI, neither RPC style is compliant with WS-I BP 1.1. You may have trouble getting other platforms to consume that service.

Comment: Document/encoded is not WS-I compliant. The formats that are WS-I complaint include Document/literal,Rpc/literal,Document/Wrapped.We can still use RPC/Literal format.

Comment: hope this answers your question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240459/soap-rpc-encoded-convert-to-rpc-literal

Comment: sorry but it doesn't help..i don't understand the problem of splitting tags..if you need the entire project to make some tests let me know.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

From your example I assume that document is an array of bytes. This is what the JAX-RPC spec says:

> 5.3.3 Array of Bytes Both byte[] and Byte[] are mapped to the xsd:base64Binary type. The mapping of the java.lang.Byte[] type to the
>   xsd:base64Binary type is now deprecated because it cannot represent
>   null values accurately. Instead, Byte[] should be mapped to a regular
>   array following the rules in section 5.3.4.

So if you really have `byte[]`, the first mapping is the correct one, if you have `Byte[]`, it's the second one (with large overhead, but capable of representing nulls). AFAIR there were bugs for example in Apache Axis that got this wrong, maybe it's also the case with your document. So check if you really use `byte[]` and which library you are using. And, like the commenters say, you shouldn't use rpc style unless you are forced to. Use document/literal binding instead.

Comment: Probably it depends on how i set the byte[] stream according to the wsdl spec given. If you want to the entire project, i'll give you, to make some tests. Becouse if i try to make a WS provider by myself and return a base64 stream, it works correctly (i mean, without tag split for each byte). Let me know where i can give it to you. Thanks

Comment: found [this](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO59433), probably helps