# Array of object parameter in Java Webservice Provider

Tags: java, web-services, soap, lotus-domino

My provider must have an array of object as input parameter, according to the WSDL:

```
<element name="classifica" type="Q4:Titolario" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
```

This is the generated method:

```
public void protoModificaProtocollo(...,...,...,Titolario[] classifica,....) {
```

How to get the input values of this array (always returns null).

**EDIT**

This is the xsd schema of the method to provide:

```
<import schemaLocation="TipoVerso.xsd" namespace="http://regione.toscana.it/rfc205/interpro.TipoVerso"/>            
<import schemaLocation="Anagrafica.xsd" namespace="http://regione.toscana.it/rfc205/interpro.Anagrafica"/>
<import schemaLocation="Titolario.xsd" namespace="http://regione.toscana.it/rfc205/interpro.Titolario"/>
    <element name="protoModificaProtocolloElement" type="tns:protoModificaProtocollo"/>

    <complexType name="protoModificaProtocollo">
      <sequence>
            <element name="numero" type="int" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
            <element name="anno" type="int" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
            <element name="verso" type="Q1:TipoVerso" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
            <element name="oggetto" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>
            <element name="classifica" type="Q4:Titolario" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
            <element name="ufficio" type="Q2:Anagrafica" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
```

and this is the xsd schema of Titolario

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <schema targetNamespace="http://regione.toscana.it/rfc205/interpro.Titolario"    
      elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
      xmlns:tns="http://regione.toscana.it/rfc205/interpro.Titolario">
   <complexType name="Titolario">
    <sequence>
        <element name="codice" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
        <element name="descrizione" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">           
            </element>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
  </schema>
```

Here the SOAP message sent:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
   xmlns:int="http://regione.toscana.it/rfc205/interpro" 
   xmlns:int1="http://regione.toscana.it/rfc205/interpro.protoModificaProtocollo"  
   xmlns:int2="http://regione.toscana.it/rfc205/interpro.Titolario" 
   xmlns:int3="http://regione.toscana.it/rfc205/interpro.Anagrafica">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
     <int:protoModificaProtocollo>
       <int1:numero>140</int1:numero>
       <int1:anno>2014</int1:anno>
       <int1:verso>P</int1:verso>
       <!--Optional:-->
       <int1:oggetto>test</int1:oggetto>
       <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
       <int1:classifica>
         <int2:codice>34</int2:codice>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <int2:descrizione>test description</int2:descrizione>
       </int1:classifica>
     </int:protoModificaProtocollo>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In the provider, this is the method:

```
public void protoModificaProtocollo(int numero, int anno, TipoVerso verso, 
  String oggetto, Titolario[] classificazione, Anagrafica[] ufficio, 
  ResponseProtocolloHolder protocollo_resp, ResponseErrorHolder response_msg_err) {

  ... some stuff here ...

  System.out.println("getCodice():" + classificazione[0].getCodice()); <-- THIS LINE ALWAYS RETURNS NULL
```

Notice that, in input parameters, if I change

```
Titolario[] classificazione
```

with

```
Titolario classificazione
```

my debug line prints:

```
34
```

**UPDATE 2**

TIA Simon, here [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cpngtkcs) you can find the full WSDL. And here [Titolario.java](http://pastebin.com/EHpa6XpC) the class for Titolario. I've noticed that when consumer call provider, Titolario constructor i call N times, depending of number of Titolario occurrences in SOAP request. As you can see, the constructor is an empty constructor.

In this moment, my protocol is RPC/encoded, just becouse i've must understand the problem reported here [Literal vs Encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344373/rpc-literal-vs-rpc-encoded-in-java-webservice-consumer) (if you please can take a look also at this...:-))

I've found some references about the problem, for example this [article](http://susanduncan.blogspot.it/2006/09/dealing-with-complex-input-params-in.html), maybe related to mine.

Anyway, i would like to know if there is a Java workaround to manage this. Thanks again!

Comment: If you are writing the provider, you need to supply a sample consumer to test with. So your question is unclear. Can you expand more?

Comment: Sure. I'm writing the provider, and i'm testing it using SoapUI. WSDL is provided by a third part, so i've generated the provider using it. In the method above, one of the parameters is an array of object (maxoccurs="unbounded" into WSDL definition). So, when i call my WS with soapUI and try to get the value passed, i always obtain "null". Hope i've explain better.

Comment: You need to expand your question more. For example post the related WSDL references for "Q4:Titolario", or SOAP request data to see if it is even sending the required object.

Comment: Not sure it's an answer, but try changing "string" to "xsd:string" (although I don't see the schema reference in your WSDL snippet, guessing it's there). I have seen issues where custom made string handlers cause issues.

Comment: Can you also clarify if what protocol are you using? eg. RPC/Literal, Doc/Literal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem!

The fact was that i've used the same given WSDL both to generate the provider and to create the SoapUI project.

Basically the trick was:

1. generate the provider in Domino using the given WSDL
2. set `RPC/Literal`, according to the `<soap:body use="literal"/>` directive
3. export the Domino WSDL of the provider
4. create the SoapUI project with it
5. use it to call services provided

That's it! ... a very stupid mistake! :-(

Comment: Glad to hear you sorted it out! :)

Comment: Thanks Simon. Can you please take a look also at the other question posted (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344373/rpc-literal-vs-rpc-encoded-in-java-webservice-consumer) and tell me what you think about?

Answer (score 0):

Without a full WSDL I can't say with 100% this is the issue.

Based on what you have so far.

1. There are known issues where the "xsd:string" is wrapped with custom string handler. I have see references before where "string" would just sit on top of "xsd:string". So I would start with changing that back to "xsd:string" and see if it helps.

2. As your web service provider has the following:

```
Titolario[] classifica
```

Normally your WSDL should create an `xxxArray` Object which your consumer sends, and not the array object itself. (Tested on Doc/Literal + RPC/Literal, as "minoccurs" only shows up on Literal).

For example:

```
public String TestProtoModificaProtocollo (Titolario x[]) { ...
```

Converts to:

```
<complexType name="Titolario">
  <sequence>
    <element name="codice" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="descrizione" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>
<complexType name="TitolarioArray">
  <sequence>
    <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item" type="impl:Titolario"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>
<element name="x" type="impl:TitolarioArray"/>
<element name="TestProtoModificaProtocolloReturn" type="xsd:string"/>
```

So your consumer would translate to:

```
public java.lang.String testProtoModificaProtocollo(TitolarioArray x) throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
```

Comment: in UPDATE 2 i've added some informations. If you need more, let me know!